# trouble understanding the php Finfo built-in class

Tags: php

I have been following along with some examples in php book when I came across a primitive image gallery example that displays all the images in a particular folder in the browser. the author uses a class called Finfo like this...

```
$fileInfo = new Finfo( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE );
```

I'm assuming Finfo is some sort of built in class in php but I can't seem to find any documentation on it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: See the first example: [`public finfo::__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can find the documentation of `finfo_file`manual here. The functions in the Fileinfo PHP extension used to determine content type and encoding of a file by looking for certain magic byte sequences at specific positions within the file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php